# Поиск числа, имеющего наибольшее число делителей

Tags: алгоритм, математика, теория-чисел

Необходимо найти число на промежутке от 1 до N, имеющее максимальное количество делителей. Если таки чисел несколько, вывести наименьшее. N может быть порядка 10^16, поэтому простой перебор не пойдет. Есть идеи?

Comment: Можно использовать решето Эратосфена: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Решето_Эратосфена

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Общие соображения

Заметим, что:

1. Величины
   **С = lg (X * p<sub>1</sub> * p<sub>2</sub> * ... * p<sub>k</sub>)** и **П = cnt(X) * lg p<sub>1</sub> * lg p<sub>2</sub> * ... * lg p<sub>k</sub>**
   -- это сумма и произведение величин **(a<sub>1</sub>+1) lg p<sub>1</sub>, (a<sub>2</sub>+1) lg p<sub>2</sub>,..., (a<sub>k</sub>+1) lg p<sub>k</sub>.**
   Не будь задача дискретной, в соответствии с теоремами о средних оптимум достигался бы при равенстве этих величин, (а с учётом потенцирования - и величин вида **p<sub>i</sub><sup>a<sub>i</sub>+1</sup>**).
2. Наш случай - дискретное приближение к оптимуму, так что эти величины должны хотя бы стремиться к равенству. А поскольку основания растут, то показатели не должны возрастать (**a<sub>1</sub>>=a<sub>2</sub>>=...>=a<sub>k</sub>**).
3. Сумма и произведение величин идут "в одном флаконе", и алгоритмы линейного динамического программирования здесь неприменимы.
4. Так как показатели степеней канонического разложения не возрастают, то требуемое оптимальное число X можно представить в виде произведения **X=P<sub>k</sub>...P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>1</sub>,** где **P<sub>k</sub>=p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>...p<sub>k</sub>**-- это произведения последовательных простых чисел (праймориалы), которые могут повторяться и которые можно протабулировать.
   И поскольку праймориал при возрастании k  растёт быстрее факториала, то их произведение для числа X подбирается очень быстро.

_[Известно](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Applications_and_properties), что

> Every highly composite number is a product of primorials_

### Алгоритм и анализ результатов

Алгоритм по п.4 рекурсивный, параметром является частное от деления числа на уже готовую часть цепочки.
Для поиска текущего оптимального праймориала (звена цепочки) ведётся перебор по убыванию в границах от "жадного" звена для текущего частного до "жадного" звена для квадратного корня из этого частного.
Перебор обрывается, когда целевая функция (количество множителей) начинает падать.
Такая схема обеспечивает решение задачи.

Дополнительный контроль невозрастания звеньев в цепочке избавляет от повторения пройденного.

Для случая **N=10<sup>18</sup>** оптимальное решение нашлось за **118** шагов и совпало с предыдущим ответом:
**X = P<sub>12</sub>P<sub>4</sub>P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>2</sub>P<sub>1</sub>P<sub>1</sub>P<sub>1</sub>P<sub>1</sub> = 2<sup>8</sup> * 3<sup>4</sup> * 5<sup>2</sup> * 7<sup>2</sup> * 11 * 13 *...* 37 = 897612484786617600,

cnt(X) = (8+1) (4+1) (2+1)<sup>2</sup> (1+1)<sup>8</sup> = 103680.**

При этом порядок величин **2<sup>9</sup>=512, 3<sup>5</sup>=243, 5<sup>3</sup>=125, 7<sup>3</sup>=343, 11<sup>2</sup>=121, ..., 37<sup>2</sup>=1369** примерно одинаков, что подтверждает теорию оптимума.

Для случая **N=10<sup>36</sup>** (**cnt(X)=127401984** множителей) понадобилось всего **168** шагов. Т.е. сложность алгоритма возрастает не быстрее логарифма. Хотя разрядность данных меняется.

Исходный код на PHP использует библиотеку **BCMath**. границу возможностей не тестировал (скорее всего, первым подведёт `int` для `cnt(X)`):

```
function prods(&$prod){
    $p = array( "2", "3", "5", "7", "11",       "13", "17", "19", "23", "29", 
            "31", "37", "41", "43", "47",   "53", "59", "61", "67", "71",
            "73", "79", "83", "89", "97",);
    $str="1"; 
    foreach($p as $val){
        $str = bcmul($str,$val);
        array_push($prod,$str);
    } 
    return 1;
}

function greedy_prod($n){
    global $p_prod;
    foreach($p_prod as $key=>$val){
        if(bccomp($val,$n)>0) break;
        $i_m=$key+1;
    }
    if (!isset($i_m)) $i_m=0;
    return $i_m;    
}

function show_chain($chain){
    $s = "[";
    foreach($chain as $len) $s = $s . sprintf("%d.",$len);  
    $s = $s."]";
    return $s; 
}

function multi_prod($chain){
    global $p_prod;     
    $m_prod = "1";
    foreach($chain as $val) $m_prod= bcmul($m_prod, $p_prod[$val-1]);
    return $m_prod;
}

function multi_count($chain){
    $cnt = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$chain[0]; $i++)  array_push($cnt, 0);
    foreach($chain as $key=>$val){
        for ($i=0; $i<$val; $i++)   $cnt[$i]++;
    }
    $count=1;
    foreach($cnt as $val) $count *= $val+1;
    return $count;
}

function maxi_count($n, &$main_chain, &$latch_chain){
    global  $maxi_counter, $p_prod;
    $maxi_counter++;

    $m_prod = multi_prod($main_chain);
    $nn = bcdiv($n,$m_prod);

    $long_chain  = greedy_prod($nn);
    if(count($main_chain)>0){
        $last = array_pop($main_chain); array_push($main_chain,$last);
        $long_chain = min($long_chain, $last);
    }
    $short_chain = greedy_prod(bcsqrt($nn));
    $short_chain = max($short_chain,1);

    if ($long_chain==0) {
        $max_count = multi_count($main_chain);
        if($max_count> multi_count($latch_chain)) $latch_chain=$main_chain;
    }
    else {
        $max_count = 0;
        for ($cur_chain=$long_chain; $cur_chain>$short_chain-1; $cur_chain--){
            array_push($main_chain,$cur_chain);     
            $counter = maxi_count($n, $main_chain, $latch_chain);
            array_pop($main_chain);
            if($counter>$max_count) $max_count = $counter;
            else break;
        }
    }       
    $s1 = show_chain($main_chain);  $s2=show_chain($latch_chain);
    print("<tr><td align=\"right\">&emsp;$m_prod</td><td align=\"right\">$max_count</td><td>$s2</td><td>$s1</td></tr>");
    return $max_count;
}   

//$N="1000000000000000000";     
$N="1000000000000000000000000000000000000";
$p_prod = array();
if (prods($p_prod)>0){
    print("<br>p_prod:<br>");   
    foreach($p_prod as $key=>$val) printf("&emsp;%d=>%s", $key, $val); 
}

$maxi_counter = 0; $chain=array(); $optimal_chain=array();
print("<br><br>maxi_count:<br>N=$N");
print('<table border="2">');
print('<tr><th>current number</th><th>multi_prod</th><th>optimal chain</th><th>current chain</th></tr>');
$max_count=maxi_count($N, $chain, $optimal_chain);
print('</table>');
printf("<br>Количество последовательностей = %d<br>Цепочка произведений = %s,<br>Kоличество множителей = %d<br>Минимальное число = %s", $maxi_counter, show_chain($optimal_chain), $max_count, multi_prod($optimal_chain));
```

Результаты для **N = 10<sup>36</sup>**:

```html
<pre>
p_prod:
 0=>2 1=>6 2=>30 3=>210 4=>2310 5=>30030 6=>510510 7=>9699690 8=>223092870
 9=>6469693230 10=>200560490130 11=>7420738134810 12=>304250263527210
 13=>13082761331670030 14=>614889782588491410 15=>32589158477190044730
 16=>1922760350154212639070 17=>117288381359406970983270
 18=>7858321551080267055879090 19=>557940830126698960967415390
 20=>40729680599249024150621323470 21=>3217644767340672907899084554130
 22=>267064515689275851355624017992790 23=>23768741896345550770650537601358310
 24=>2305567963945518424753102147331756070

maxi_count:
N=1000000000000000000000000000000000000
    current number                  multi_prod optimal chain current chain
 713062256890366523119516128040749300 56623104 [24.3.] [24.3.]
 855674708268439827743419353648899160 67108864 [24.2.2.] [24.2.2.]
 570449805512293218495612902432599440 62914560 [24.2.2.] [24.2.1.1.]
 285224902756146609247806451216299720 62914560 [24.2.2.] [24.2.1.]
 142612451378073304623903225608149860 67108864 [24.2.2.] [24.2.]
 23768741896345550770650537601358310 67108864 [24.2.2.] [24.]
 616919031242227216631491481563344900 63700992 [24.2.2.] [23.5.]
 673002579536975145416172525341830800 94371840 [23.4.2.1.] [23.4.2.1.]
 336501289768487572708086262670915400 94371840 [23.4.2.1.] [23.4.2.]
 897336772715966860554896700455774400 99090432 [23.4.1.1.1.1.] [23.4.1.1.1.1.]
 448668386357983430277448350227887200 99090432 [23.4.1.1.1.1.] [23.4.1.1.1.]
 224334193178991715138724175113943600 99090432 [23.4.1.1.1.1.] [23.4.1.1.]
 112167096589495857569362087556971800 99090432 [23.4.1.1.1.1.] [23.4.1.]
 56083548294747928784681043778485900 99090432 [23.4.1.1.1.1.] [23.4.]
 961432256481393064880246464774044000 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.3.1.1.]
 480716128240696532440123232387022000 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.3.1.]
 240358064120348266220061616193511000 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.3.]
 576859353888835838928147878864426400 94371840 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.2.2.1.]
 288429676944417919464073939432213200 94371840 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.2.2.]
 769145805185114451904197171819235200 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.2.1.1.1.1.]
 384572902592557225952098585909617600 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.2.1.1.1.]
 192286451296278612976049292954808800 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.2.1.1.]
 96143225648139306488024646477404400 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.2.1.]
 48071612824069653244012323238702200 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.2.]
 8011935470678275540668720539783700 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.3.]
 267064515689275851355624017992790 100663296 [23.3.3.1.1.] [23.]
 579755234179442444545257054963143400 84934656 [23.3.3.1.1.] [22.6.2.]
 773006978905923259393676073284191200 95551488 [23.3.3.1.1.] [22.6.1.1.1.]
 386503489452961629696838036642095600 95551488 [23.3.3.1.1.] [22.6.1.1.]
 193251744726480814848419018321047800 95551488 [23.3.3.1.1.] [22.6.1.]
 96625872363240407424209509160523900 95551488 [23.3.3.1.1.] [22.6.]
 891931129506834530069626238404836000 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.3.1.1.]
 445965564753417265034813119202418000 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.3.1.]
 222982782376708632517406559601209000 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.3.]
 535158677704100718041775743042901600 106168320 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.2.2.1.]
 267579338852050359020887871521450800 106168320 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.2.2.]
 713544903605467624055700990723868800 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.2.1.1.1.1.]
 356772451802733812027850495361934400 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.2.1.1.1.]
 178386225901366906013925247680967200 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.2.1.1.]
 89193112950683453006962623840483600 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.2.1.]
 44596556475341726503481311920241800 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.2.]
 7432759412556954417246885320040300 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.5.]
 851388805438342051430097773022798000 104857600 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.4.4.2.]
 567592536958894700953398515348532000 100663296 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.4.4.1.1.]
 283796268479447350476699257674266000 100663296 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.4.4.1.]
 141898134239723675238349628837133000 104857600 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.4.4.]
 608134861027387179592926980730570000 98304000 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.4.3.3.]
 729761833232864615511512376876684000 113246208 [22.5.3.1.1.] [22.4.3.2.2.]
 973015777643819487348683169168912000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.]
 486507888821909743674341584584456000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [22.4.3.2.1.1.]
 243253944410954871837170792292228000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [22.4.3.2.1.]
 121626972205477435918585396146114000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [22.4.3.2.]
 20271162034246239319764232691019000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [22.4.3.]
 675705401141541310658807756367300 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [22.4.]
 3217644767340672907899084554130 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [22.]
 790130551223459534127080290097448600 71663616 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.8.1.]
 395065275611729767063540145048724300 71663616 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.8.]
 623787277281678579574010755340091000 84934656 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.7.3.]
 748544732738014295488812906408109200 99532800 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.7.2.2.]
 998059643650685727318417208544145600 111476736 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.7.2.1.1.1.]
 499029821825342863659208604272072800 111476736 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.7.2.1.1.]
 249514910912671431829604302136036400 111476736 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.7.2.1.]
 124757455456335715914802151068018200 111476736 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.7.2.]
 20792909242722619319133691844669700 111476736 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.7.]
 513707169526088242002126504397722000 94371840 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.4.1.]
 256853584763044121001063252198861000 94371840 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.4.]
 880640862044722700575074007538952000 123863040 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.2.1.1.]
 440320431022361350287537003769476000 123863040 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.2.1.]
 220160215511180675143768501884738000 123863040 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.2.]
 587093908029815133716716005025968000 113246208 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.1.1.1.1.]
 293546954014907566858358002512984000 113246208 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.1.1.1.]
 146773477007453783429179001256492000 113246208 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.1.1.]
 73386738503726891714589500628246000 113246208 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.1.]
 36693369251863445857294750314123000 123863040 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.3.]
 528384517226833620345044404523371200 111476736 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.2.2.1.]
 264192258613416810172522202261685600 111476736 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.2.2.]
 704512689635778160460059206031161600 119439360 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.2.1.1.1.1.]
 352256344817889080230029603015580800 119439360 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.2.1.1.1.]
 176128172408944540115014801507790400 119439360 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.2.1.1.]
 88064086204472270057507400753895200 119439360 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.2.1.]
 44032043102236135028753700376947600 119439360 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.2.]
 7338673850372689171458950062824600 119439360 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.2.]
 1223112308395448195243158343804100 123863040 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.6.]
 869350594582610871080521776673068000 100663296 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.5.1.1.]
 434675297291305435540260888336534000 100663296 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.5.1.]
 217337648645652717770130444168267000 100663296 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.5.]
 592739041760871048463992120458910000 98304000 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.4.3.]
 711286850113045258156790544550692000 113246208 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.4.2.2.]
 948382466817393677542387392734256000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.4.2.1.1.1.]
 474191233408696838771193696367128000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.4.2.1.1.]
 237095616704348419385596848183564000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.4.2.1.]
 118547808352174209692798424091782000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.4.2.]
 19757968058695701615466404015297000 125829120 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.4.]
 508062035795032327254850388964780000 106168320 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.3.2.]
 677416047726709769673133851953040000 117964800 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.3.1.1.1.]
 338708023863354884836566925976520000 117964800 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.3.1.1.]
 169354011931677442418283462988260000 117964800 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.3.1.]
 84677005965838721209141731494130000 117964800 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.3.]
 609674442954038792705820466757736000 115605504 [22.4.3.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.2.2.2.]
 812899257272051723607760622343648000 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.]
 406449628636025861803880311171824000 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.]
 203224814318012930901940155585912000 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.2.2.1.]
 101612407159006465450970077792956000 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.2.2.]
 16935401193167744241828346298826000 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.2.]
 2822566865527957373638057716471000 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.3.]
 94085562184265245787935257215700 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.5.]
 40729680599249024150621323470     127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [21.]
 746835726498886408969432055023615800 71663616 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.9.2.]
 995780968665181878625909406698154400 80621568 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.9.1.1.1.]
 497890484332590939312954703349077200 80621568 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.9.1.1.]
 248945242166295469656477351674538600 80621568 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.9.1.]
 124472621083147734828238675837269300 80621568 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.9.]
 974133556302895316047085289161238000 99532800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.3.2.]
 649422370868596877364723526107492000 95551488 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.3.1.1.]
 324711185434298438682361763053746000 95551488 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.3.1.]
 162355592717149219341180881526873000 99532800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.3.]
 779306845042316252837668231328990400 104509440 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.2.1.1.]
 389653422521158126418834115664495200 104509440 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.2.1.]
 194826711260579063209417057832247600 104509440 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.2.]
 519537896694877501891778820885993600 95551488 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.1.1.1.1.]
 259768948347438750945889410442996800 95551488 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.1.1.1.]
 129884474173719375472944705221498400 95551488 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.1.1.]
 64942237086859687736472352610749200 95551488 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.1.]
 32471118543429843868236176305374600 104509440 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.2.]
 5411853090571640644706029384229100 104509440 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.8.]
 657967402064236309961627783029959000 75497472 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.5.]
 717782620433712338139957581487228000 106168320 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.4.2.1.]
 358891310216856169069978790743614000 106168320 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.4.2.]
 957043493911616450853276775316304000 113246208 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.4.1.1.1.1.]
 478521746955808225426638387658152000 113246208 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.4.1.1.1.]
 239260873477904112713319193829076000 113246208 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.4.1.1.]
 119630436738952056356659596914538000 113246208 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.4.1.]
 59815218369476028178329798457269000 113246208 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.4.]
 512701871738365955814255415348020000 99532800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.3.1.]
 256350935869182977907127707674010000 99532800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.3.]
 615242246086039146977106498417624000 111476736 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.2.2.1.]
 307621123043019573488553249208812000 111476736 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.2.2.]
 820322994781385529302808664556832000 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.2.1.1.1.1.]
 410161497390692764651404332278416000 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.2.1.1.1.]
 205080748695346382325702166139208000 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.2.1.1.]
 102540374347673191162851083069604000 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.2.1.]
 51270187173836595581425541534802000 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.2.]
 8545031195639432596904256922467000 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.3.]
 284834373187981086563475230748900 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.7.]
 503151542755004237029480069375851000 67108864 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.6.]
 928895155855392437592886281924648000 110100480 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.2.1.1.]
 464447577927696218796443140962324000 110100480 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.2.1.]
 232223788963848109398221570481162000 110100480 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.2.]
 619263437236928291728590854616432000 100663296 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.1.1.1.1.]
 309631718618464145864295427308216000 100663296 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.1.1.1.]
 154815859309232072932147713654108000 100663296 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.1.1.]
 77407929654616036466073856827054000 100663296 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.1.]
 38703964827308018233036928413527000 110100480 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.5.]
 738893873975880348085250451530970000 92160000 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.4.]
 633337606265040298358786101312260000 106168320 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.3.2.]
 844450141686720397811714801749680000 117964800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.3.1.1.1.]
 422225070843360198905857400874840000 117964800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.3.1.1.]
 211112535421680099452928700437420000 117964800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.3.1.]
 105556267710840049726464350218710000 117964800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.3.]
 760005127518048358030543321574712000 115605504 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.2.2.2.]
 506670085012032238687028881049808000 113246208 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.2.2.1.1.]
 253335042506016119343514440524904000 113246208 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.2.2.1.]
 126667521253008059671757220262452000 115605504 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.2.2.]
 21111253542168009945292870043742000 115605504 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.2.]
 3518542257028001657548811673957000 117964800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.4.]
 16754963128704769797851484161700 117964800 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.6.]
 557940830126698960967415390 119439360 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] [20.]
 1 127401984 [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.] []

Количество последовательностей = 168
Цепочка произведений = [21.5.3.2.2.1.1.1.],
Kоличество множителей = 127401984
Минимальное число = 812899257272051723607760622343648000 

</pre>
```

### Расширенная постановка задачи

Итак, мы нашли оптимальное решение задачи, которому соответствует минимальное среди `n<N`. В приведённом примере отношение `N/n=1.23`. Но если бы потребовалось найти все возможные числа до `N` с полученным количеством делителей, то возникла бы комбинаторная задача на тему возможных обменов простых множителей.

Answer (score 5):

Существует решение и для чисел до 10^18.

Обозначения

- Пусть искомое число X представимо в виде:
  (p1^a1)*(p2^a2)*...*(pk^ak), где pi - простое число, причем pi < pj
  при i < j, т.е. простые числа взяты по возрастанию.
- Количество делителей cnt(X) = (a1+1)*(a2+1)*...*(ak+1) - это
  справедливо, даже если какие то степени ai = 0

Наблюдения:

- Количество делителей зависят от показателей степени простого числа, которое в него входит, но не от самого простого числа.
- Пусть последней ненулевой степенью будет ak, надо заметить, что нам не выгодно что бы на отрезке i=1...k-1 была ai=0, это значило бы, что мы можем сдвинуть массив степеней влево и при этом: число уменьшится, количество делителей останется таким же.
- Так же нам выгодно, что бы массив ai создавал невозрастающую последовательность, иначе мы можем отсортировать данным массив по не возрастанию и мы получим меньшее число с таким же количеством делителей.
- Количество простых чисел которое мы хотим рассматривается k<=15 для N<=10^18. Из соображений, что если перемножить первые 16 простых чисел получим число превышающее 10^18.

Из этих соображений строим алгоритм:

Необходимо перебрать все возможные последовательности ai не более из 15 элементов, удовлетворяющие следующим условиям:

- последовательность ai - невозрастающая
- (p1^a1)*(p2^a2)*...*(pk^ak) <= N

Среди таких последовательностей выбрать ту, где (a1+1)*(a2+1)*...*(ak+1) - максимально.

Исходный код на С++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef long long lint;
lint p[15]={2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47};
lint answer, cntForAnswer;
lint N;

/*
index - индекс простого числа p[index], на который сейчас будем пробовать умножать
lastA - значение предыдущего значения ai, что бы составить не возрастающую (a[i+1]<=a[i])
value - текущее значние (p1^a1)*(p2^a2)*...*(pi^ai)
cntForValue - количество делителей числа value
*/
void findMax(int index, int lastA, lint value, lint cntForValue)
{
    if (cntForValue > cntForAnswer || (cntForValue == cntForAnswer && value < answer))
    {
        answer = value;
        cntForAnswer = cntForValue;
    }
    if(index == 15) return;
    for(int a = 1; a <= lastA; a++)
    {
        lint temp = value * p[index];
        // проверка на переполнение
        if(temp/p[index] != value) return;
        // если получили число больше N
        if(temp > N) break;
        value = temp;
        findMax(index+1, a, value, cntForValue*(a+1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> N;
    findMax(0, 64, 1, 1);
    cout << "Answer: " << answer << endl;
    cout << "Count: " << cntForAnswer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Для N = 10^18, answer = 897612484786617600, количество делителей равно 103680. Количество перебранных последовательностей чуть больше 32000.

Answer (score -1):

Только перебор, но не до N, а до sqrt(N). В данном случае количество перебираемых чисел не превышает 10^8.

Comment: А если пытаться как-то построить число без перебора? Например, умножать друг на друга делители в порядке возрастания до тех пор, пока произведение не превысит N?

Comment: Вы раньше умрёте, чем такое решето сумеет найти достаточно изобильных чисел где-нибудь в районе 10¹⁵. Не забывайте, что искать делители надо не *одного* числа *N*, а большого количества кандидатов, **не превосходящих *N***.

Comment: Либо я не понял задание, либо этот ответ совсем не верный. Например возьмем N = 4. По вашему, перебор надо делать до 2, и ответом будет 2, т.к. у него есть 2 делителя (1, 2). На самом же деле правильный ответ -- 4, у которого есть 3 делителя (1, 2, 4).