# Задача о размере карт, Яндекс.Алгоритм.2015

Tags: java, алгоритм, яндекс-карты

Если кто не знает, на днях состоялся квалификационный раунд Яндекс.Алгоритм.2015. Формат раунда такой, что дается 100 минут и 7 задач, которые необходимо решить. Собственно, не сказать, что задачи сложные, но тем не менее трудности возникли.
Вообще интересно было бы устроить обсуждение вместе с участниками соревнования по поводу решения задач. В данной теме обсуждается задача о ***"Размере карты"***.
Впрочем, любой желающий, может поучаствовать в решение данной задачи.

**Условие:**
Алексей — обычный пользователь интернета. Однажды, пользуясь сервисом Яндекс.Карты, Алексей задумался: ведь наверняка итоговое изображение на экране формируется из нескольких прямоугольных изображений меньшего размера, получаемых с сервера. Алексею стало интересно: сколько существует возможных размеров изображений таких, что из них можно составить картинку, видимую на экране.
Видимая область карты занимает N × M пикселей на экране Алексея. Его интересует количество пар (A, B) (1 ≤ A ≤ N, 1 ≤ B ≤ M) таких, что прямоугольниками A × B можно выложить прямоугольник N × M, размещая их вплотную друг с другом, без накладываний и поворотов. При этом Алексей уверен, что посылать большие картинки с сервера очень накладно, и поэтому его не интересуют пары (A, B), для которых A ⋅ B > R. Также Алексей понимает, что посылать большое количество маленьких картинок тоже невыгодно, поэтому его не интересуют пары (A, B), для которых A ⋅ B < L.
Помогите Алексею ответить на интересующий его вопрос.

**Формат ввода:**
Единственная строка входного файла содержит четыре целых числа N, M, L, R (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10^9, 1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ N ⋅ M), разделённых пробелами.

**Формат вывода:**
Выведите единственное число: количество возможных пар, удовлетворяющих требованиям Алексея.

*Пример 1*
Ввод
4 4 1 7
Вывод
6

*Пример 2*
Ввод
1 30 10 17
Вывод
2

*Пример 3*
Ввод
5 5 10 20
Вывод
0

**Примечания:**
В первом тесте возможными вариантами являются 1× 1, 1× 2, 2× 1, 2× 2, 1× 4 и 4× 1. 
В во втором тесте возможными вариантами являются 1× 10 и 1× 15.
В третьем тесте произошла магия, и Алексей увидел изображение, которое никак не могло быть составлено, если его предположения верны.

*Ограничение времени:*  1 секунда

*Ограничение памяти:*   64Mb

*Ввод:* стандартный ввод или input.txt

*Вывод:*    стандартный вывод или output.txt

Ниже мой вариант решения задачи на java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Task5
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");

    int N = Integer.valueOf(line[0]);
    int M = Integer.valueOf(line[1]);
    int L = Integer.valueOf(line[2]);
    int R = Integer.valueOf(line[3]);

    int  count = 0;
    for (int  ab = L; ab <= R; ab++)
    {
        //long nm = N * M;
        if ((N * M) % ab == 0)
        {
            for (int  a = 1; a <= N; a++)
            {
                if ((ab % a == 0) && ( ab / a <= M) && (M % (ab / a) == 0) && (N % a == 0))
                {
                    //System.out.println(a + " x " + ab / a);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

Заваливается он на 15 тесте, с ошибкой RE ("Ошибка во время исполнения"), подумал я, что ошибка в размерности int, но нет, по заданию числа не превышают 10^9.
Но все же, попробовав long вместо int, 14 тест завалился с сообщением TL ("Лимит времени исполнения"). Тогда я попробовал реализовать задачу на c++, но так и не преодолел 15 тест.

Надеюсь, что это тема не останется не замеченной.

**#UPD1**
Нашел еще более эффективное решение по времени:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Task5_2
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");

        long N = Integer.valueOf(line[0]);
        long M = Integer.valueOf(line[1]);
        long L = Integer.valueOf(line[2]);
        long R = Integer.valueOf(line[3]);

        ArrayList<Long> nMod = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Long> mMod = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for (long n = 1; n <= N / 2; n++)
            if (N % n == 0)
                nMod.add(n);
        nMod.add(N);

        for (long m = 1; m <= M / 2; m++)
            if (M % m == 0)
                mMod.add(m);
        mMod.add(M);

        int count = 0;
        for(long n : nMod)
            for (long m : mMod)
                if ((n * m >= L) && (n * m <= R))
                    count++;

        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

Хотя этот вариант не решил проблему прохождения 15-го теста. По прежнему RE.

**#UPD2** Собственно программа, которая проходит все 54 теста.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Task5_5_1
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");

        long N = Long.valueOf(line[0]);
        long M = Long.valueOf(line[1]);
        long L = Long.valueOf(line[2]);
        long R = Long.valueOf(line[3]);


        boolean isPrimeN = isPrime(N);
        boolean isPrimeM = isPrime(M);

        ArrayList<Long> divsN = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Long> divsM = new ArrayList<Long>();
        long count = 0;

        if (isPrimeN)
        {
            divsN.add(1L);
            if (N != 1) divsN.add(N);
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<Long> primeFactorsN = getPrimeFactors(N);
            divsN = getDivs(primeFactorsN);
        }

        if (isPrimeM)
        {
            divsM.add(1L);
            if (M != 1) divsM.add(M);
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<Long> primeFactorsM = getPrimeFactors(M);
            divsM = getDivs(primeFactorsM);
        }

        for (long divN : divsN)
            for (long divM : divsM)
            {
                long divNM = divN * divM;
                if (divNM >= L && divNM <= R)
                {
                    //System.out.println(divN + " x " + divM);
                    count++;
                }
            }

        System.out.println(count);

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(long num)
    {
        long sqrtNum = (long) Math.sqrt(num);
        for (long i = 2; i <= sqrtNum; i++)
        {
            if (sqrtNum % i == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Long> getPrimeFactors(long num)
    {   
        ArrayList<Long> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for (long i = 2; i <= num / i; i++)
        {
            while(num % i == 0)
            {
                primeFactors.add(i);
                num /= i;
            }
        }
        if (num > 1)
            primeFactors.add(num);

        return primeFactors;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Long> getDivs(ArrayList<Long> primeFactors)
    {
        ArrayList<Long> divs = new ArrayList<Long>();
        long n = primeFactors.size();
        long rank = (long) Math.pow(2, n);

        for (long i = 0; i < rank; i++)
        {
            String bin = Long.toBinaryString(i);
            while (bin.length() != n)
                bin = '0' + bin;

            long num = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < bin.length(); j++)
            {
                if (bin.charAt(j) == '1')
                    num *= primeFactors.get(j);
            }

            if (!divs.contains(num))
                divs.add(num);
        }

        return divs;
    }
}
```

P.S. Я немного подстраховался, заведя все переменный и контейнеры типом long, хотя по сути, можно было бы для переменный M и N выбрать тип int, но в таком случае постоянно заваливался 15 тест, хз почему (плохо, что не предоставляется содержимое заваленных тестов).

**#UPD3** Кстати, задачу о ранжирование документов можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425749/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-2015).

Comment: Уберите пожалуйста из вопроса Алексея. *Алексей - обычный пользователь интернета. Алексей задумался.* При прочтении  складывается ясное впечатление, что для автора текста задачи обычные пользователи - идиоты.

Comment: По поводу вашего решения, то видимо полный перебор и проверка всех пар (a,b) это плохая идея. Скорее всего есть какая-то комбинаторная формула вообще позволяющая найти за O(1) это число. Не могу точно сказать, но общее количество прямоугольников в прямоугольнике m*n легко считается  как произведение `C(n+1,2)*C(m+1,2) = n*m*(n+1)*(m+1)/4`

Comment: Хотя нет кажется я ошибся выше. Это просто задача-шутка на факторизацию целых чисел, перенесенная в два измерения. Никак ее быстро не решить без таблицы с делителями или [квантового компьютера](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm). [В этом вопросе есть также список обычных алгоритмов факторизации.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-factorization-algorithm)

Comment: Runtime error у Вас, судя по всему, возникает из-за строк `... = Integer.valueOf(line[...])`. Потому что не все допустимые по условию значения умещаются в тип int — L и R вполне могут быть равны 10^18. Замена тут `Integer` на `Long` должна помочь.

Comment: Действительно! Не заметил, когда int на long заменял.
Правда, заменив лишь L и R, я стал получать WA. Но заменив все переменные и контейнеры на тип long, программа, к удивлению, проработала до 17 теста, где закончилась TL.

Answer (score 4):

Вот эта прога прошла все тесты, максимальное время 3 мс (тест #40)

```pascal
Program E;
Type TPrime = record P: Cardinal; A, B: Integer; end;
Var
  N, M, D: Cardinal;
  LL, RR: Int64;
  Primes: array[0..10000]of TPrime;
  PrimesCtr, Res: Integer;

  Procedure TestD;
  begin
    if (N mod D = 0) or (M mod D = 0) then
      with Primes[PrimesCtr] do begin
        P := D; A := 0; B := 0;
        while N mod D = 0 do begin N := N div D; inc(A); end;
        while M mod D = 0 do begin M := M div D; inc(B); end;
        inc(PrimesCtr);
      end;
    inc(D, 1 + D mod 2);
  end;

  Function Min2(x,y: Integer): Integer; 
    begin if x < y then Result := x else Result := y; end;
  Function Min4(x,y,z,t: Integer): Integer; 
    begin Result := Min2(Min2(x,y), Min2(z,t)); end;

  Procedure Recurs(Index: Integer; Prod: Int64; R: Integer);
    var L: Integer;
  begin
    if Index > 0 then begin
      dec(Index);
      with Primes[Index] do begin
        for L := 0 to A + B do begin
          if L > 0 then Prod := Prod * P;
          if Prod <= RR then 
            Recurs(Index, Prod, R * (1 + Min4(L, A, B, A+B-L)));
        end;
      end;
    end else
      if Prod >= LL then inc(Res, R);
  end;

Begin
  Readln(N, M, LL, RR);
  D := 2; PrimesCtr := 0;
  repeat TestD until (D*D > N) and (D*D > M);
  D := N; if D > 1 then TestD;
  D := M; if D > 1 then TestD;
  Res := 0;
  Recurs(PrimesCtr, 1, 1);
  Writeln(Res);
End.
```

Comment: Может Вы опишите алгоритм, если Вам не сложно, просто не все моменты удалось понять из кода.

Comment: @yol - Сначала раскладываем числа M и N на множители, а потом тупо перебираем все возможные произведения AB в виде разложения на множители.  Зная AB, несложно подсчитать количество пар (A, B) с таким произведением.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения задачи необходимо так или иначе найти [все делители чисел(факторизовать) N и M](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB). Это автоматически означает экспоненциальную сложность алгоритма.

Чтобы её решить быстро(за полиномиальное время или меньше) Вам необходимо либо воспользоваться 64 мегабайтной таблицей простых делителей либо раздобыть квантовый компьютер и запустить на нем [алгоритм Шора](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm).

Других вариантов я не знаю и всякие выкрутасы с заменой языков программирования или переиначиванием потока управления и типов данных в [наивном экспоненциальном алгоритме перебора делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9), который вы по сути предлагаете Вам никак не помогут.

Скорее всего это просто шутка Яндекса.(Или может они просто все еще надеются, что какой-нибудь математик мирового уровня ВНЕЗАПНО прибежит к ним на конкурс с доказательством P=NP)

Также на всякий случай прилагаю список хороших субэкспоненциальных алгоритмов факторизации, [позаимствованный мной с большого SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267146/what-is-the-fastest-factorization-algorithm):

- Число порядка 2^16: Таблица делителей.
- Число порядка 2^70: [Модификация Ричарда Брента](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub051.html) [Ρ-алгоритма Полларда.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A1-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0)
- Число порядка 10^50: [Эллиптическими кривыми.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85)
- Число порядка 10^100: [Метод квадратичного решета.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)
- Число порядка и больше 10^100: [Общий метод решета числового поля.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Также рекомендую [ознакомиться с хитроумной математической проблемой P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)

Comment: Чтобы факторизовать число меньше миллиарда, достаточно школьного метода - перебрать всего sqrt(10^9) делителей, т.е., за примерно 30000 операций.

Comment: @Egor Т.е. вы думаете тест на время выполнения составлен таким образом, что он не срабатвыает на переборе до n/2 и срабатывает при переборе до sqrt(n) c последующим сокращением. Легко может быть и такое.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 ≤ N, ≤ 10^9, 1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ N ⋅ M

На M ограничение не дано. Но я предполагаю, что тоже 10^9. Тогда L и R до 10^18. Но даже если я не заметил, и где-то оговаривается, что *все* числа до 10^9, то

> if ((N * M) % ab == 0)

их произведение всё равно до 10^18.

Comment: Да, M тоже имеет ограничение 10^9. 
А насчет "произведения N и M имеющее ограничение 10^18" и что из этого следует?

Comment: @yol, из этого следует, что в процитированной строке происходит переполнение, потому что в int помещается только 2*10^9 примерно.

Answer (score 0):

Факты:

- Найти все делители числа T можно за время O(sqrt(T)). [link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)
- Для любого натурального числа T <= 10^9 количество делителей не превосходит 1500. [Можете проверить...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/352481/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/460254#460254)

Решение:

- Находим делители a1,a2...an числа N.
- Находим делители b1,b2...bn числа M.
- Перебираем все возможные пары ai*bj и проверяем, что они удовлитворяют заданным условиям.

Итоговая сложность O(sqrt(N*M))